# Approximation of a quotient that involves the Lambert function.

Tags: asymptotics, approximation, lambert-w

I would like to find an asymptotic upper bound for
$$\frac{-\ln n}{W(- \ln^{-c}n)}$$
where $c$ is positive and $W$ is the Lambert function. More precisely, I want something which dominates this quotient asymptotically. The bound should be quite tight.

Can we say that $\frac{-\ln n}{W(- \ln^{-c}n)}=O\left(\frac{\ln n}{\ln \ln n}\right)$ ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more accurate asymptotic series can be obtained with more terms.

but, before, one can observe that $y=\frac{-\ln n}{W(- \ln^{-c}n)}$ is not real if $n<e^{e^{1/c}}$

This means that, for small values of $c$, $n$ has to be very large :

In case of $c=0.2$ for example, $y$ is not real if $n<10^{64}$ (roughly)

In case of $c=0.5$ for example, $y$ is not real if $n<1618$

So, I doubt that small values of $c$ ( i.e.: $c<<1$) be encountered in real world. If they are, what does mean so big values of $n$ and correlatively of $y$ ?

[image]

To be accurate, the number of terms depends on $c$. The power of last term $\ln(n)$ must be negative. For example with the above series, the power of the fourth term is negative only if $c>0.5$

Other example : if $c=0.2$ the series requires more than 7 terms.

The next table shows some numerical results :

[image]

SECOND BRANCH OF THE W-function (noted $W_{-1}$ ) :

An approximate can be found in page 13 of the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function

$$W_{-1}(X)=-\theta-\ln\left(\theta+\ln\left(\theta+\ln\left(\theta+\ln\left( \theta+...\right) \right) \right) \right) \qquad\text{where}\qquad\theta=-\ln(-X)$$
Here we have : $$X=-\ln^{-c}(n)\quad\to\quad\theta=c\:\ln(\ln(n))$$

The next table of numerical examples shows that a large number of terms are necessary to a good accuracy, especially in case of small $c$.

[image]

NOTE :

The therm $\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(\ln(n))}$ appears in the simplest form of approximate (with only one term):
$$\frac{-\ln n}{W_{-1}(- \ln^{-c}n)}\simeq \frac{\ln(n)}{c\:\ln(\ln(n))}$$
Of course, the accuracy is much better in using the above formula with as many terms as possible.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer @JJacquelin. So, what branch should I use ? $W_{-1}$ or $W_0$ ?

Comment: What do you want to do with this formula ?

Comment: I want to solve the equation $xn^{1/x}=(\ln n)^{1+c}$ with an asymptotic approximation. I had the intuition that $x=O(\ln n/(\ln \ln n))$.

Comment: Why do you think that this equation has only one root  and then only one asymptotic approximation ?

Comment: I understood that there are two solutions, and, in fact, that disturbed me a little. Thanks again for your answer :-)

Comment: You're welcome. For the two solutions respectively : $x_1=O\left(\ln^{c+1}(n)\right)$ and $x_2=O\left( \frac{\ln(n)}{c\:\ln(\ln(n))}  \right)$

Answer (score 1):

For $c>0$ and $n$ sufficient large the dominator becomes $W(0)$ :

$W(-(\ln n)^{-c})\to W(0)=0$ for $n\to \infty$.

It’s $\frac{1}{W(x)}= \frac{1}{x}e^{W(x)}$ by definition.

Substitute $x$ by $-(\ln n)^{-c}$.

Then your term becomes $(\ln n)^{c+1}$; that’s very different to $\frac{\ln n}{\ln\ln n}$.

EDIT:

I don’t know exactly what you mean, but I will try.

$x n^{\frac{1}{x}}=y_n$ with $y_n:=(\ln n)^{1+c}$

Lambert is not necessary, it’s enough to know:

$n^{\frac{1}{y_n}}=(n^{\frac{1}{x}})^{(n^{-\frac{1}{x}})}\le e^{\frac{1}{e}}$

Let be $n^{\frac{1}{y_n}}>1$.

Then for $n^{\frac{1}{x}}$ you’ve two solutions, if $1<n^{\frac{1}{y_n}}<e^{\frac{1}{e}}$, one solution if $n^{\frac{1}{y_n}}=e^{\frac{1}{e}}$ and no solution, if $n^{\frac{1}{y_n}}>e^{\frac{1}{e}}$.

Two solutions: (1) $1<n^{\frac{1}{x}}<e$ => $x>\ln n$ , (2) $e<n^{\frac{1}{x}}$ => $x<\ln n$

One solution: $n^{\frac{1}{x}}=e$ => $x=\ln n$

And: $1<n^{\frac{1}{y_n}}\le e^{\frac{1}{e}}$ => $y_n>e\ln n$ => $n>e^{e^{\frac{1}{c}}}$

If you choose solution (1), you get $x>e^{\frac{1}{c}}$. For $c\to 0$ only solution (2) remains.

Is this the answer to your question (more or less) ?!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about the second branch $W_{-1}$ ? I'm reading on Wiki that when $x$ approaches $0$, we have $W_{-1}(x)$ close to $\ln(-x) - \ln(-\ln(-x))$.

Comment: In fact I'm looking for a slightly tighter bound. For information: I've obtained $x=\frac{-\ln n}{W(- \ln^{-c}n)}$ by solving the equation $xn^{1/x}= (\ln n)^{1+c}$. I know that $x$ should lower than $\ln n$, but I don't know in what extent...

Comment: Have extended my answer above.

Comment: Thanks you @user90369. Your proof is interesting. Is $k^{1/k}$ always lower than $e^{1/e}$ ? I don't know this property. Using the Lambert function allows to obtain an accurate solution (with a denominator which is function of $n$). It is true that I'm interested in a solution $x < \ln n$; but I would prefer a tight asymptotic upper bound. To do that, I think we have to use the branch $W_{-1}$, but I don't know if we can. Thanks again.

Comment: It’s nice to see, that in the case of two solutions for $y=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ a parameterization is possible: $x_1=x_1(t):=(1+\frac{1}{t})^t$  <=> $x_2=x_2(t):=(1+\frac{1}{t})^{t+1}$                    
For example: $t:=1$ => $x_1=2$ and $x_2=4$ .
And: $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}x_1(t)=e=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}x_2(t)$ .  
For $0<t_1<t_2$ we have $x_1(t_1)<x_1(t_2)$ and $x_2(t_1)>x_2(t_2)$ and therefore $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ has his Maximum at $e^{\frac{1}{e}}$.

Comment: Yes, you have to use W_{-1} instead of W.

Comment: Thanks very much @user90369. If have to use $W_{-1}$, then we have $\frac{-\ln n}{W_{-1}(- \ln^{-c}n)}=O\left(\frac{\ln n}{\ln \ln n}\right)$. What is the argument for using $W_{-1}$ ? Thanks again.

Comment: W(x) is limited, |W_{-1}(x)| can increase endless. It depends what you like to know. It's shown above, that $x<\ln n$ and $W_{-1}$ cohere.

Comment: I don't understand very well. You say that I have to choose what I want ?

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood you. It's shown above, that $x<\ln n$ and $W_{-1}$ cohere. $W_{-1}$ has to be used for solution (2). - Generally: the problem to use Lambert is it's unpleasant definition.

Comment: You are welcome. :-) --- You will have less problems, if you look at the the graph of $y=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ and solve this equation by using Lambert.